# PowerShell Kill all dead connections

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0

How do I kill all dead connections?

I have exception caught in $error message:

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "KillAllProcesses" with "1" argument(s): "Drop all active
>   database connections failed for Server '172.0.0.1'. " --->
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Drop all
>   active database connections failed for Server '172.0.0.1'.  --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: 
>                               An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Process ID 68 is not an active
>   process ID.

now my ps script:

```
 # ==== check if db exists and drop db ==== #

        if($srv.Databases.Contains("$DbName"))
        { 
                Write-Host -fore Yellow "Dropping existing db: $DbName on Server: $Server"

                $srv.KillAllProcesses($DbName)
                $srv.KillDatabase($DbName)

                # show us errors
                $error = $_.Exception
                while ( $error.InnerException )
                {
                    $error = $error.InnerException
                    Write-Host -fore Red $error.Message                     
                }

                Write-Host -fore Yellow "Completed deleting db: $DbName on Server: $Server"
        } 
        else { 
            Write-Host "Database $DbName does not exists"
        }     


    # ==== check if db exists and drop db ==== #
```

I thought that KillAllProcesses kills everything but according to error message it does not.

Any ideas how to solve this?